# how to fix 'pygame.error: Couldn't open .png' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm, python-3.8

[image]enter image description here

```
import pygame    
import os   
import tkinter as tk   
from tkinter import messagebox   
import sys

pygame.init()
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\[Name]\Desktop\Projects\PythonProjects\Python Practice\Projects\Games\Golf Game")

print(os.getcwd())

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 600))
title = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'GOLF GAME LOGO.png'))

win.blit(title, (640, 650))

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: The path `Golf Game\imgs\GOLF GAME LOGO.png` is correct?

Comment: Have you tried adding 'print(os.getcwd())' to the beginning of your script to see where it is looking?

Comment: @AMC yes that is the path within the directory im working in, yes

Comment: @tacticalmovephase you were right it was not in the right directory

however now the image wont open and no errors are showing up

Answer (score 0):

Per my earlier comment you ran `print(os.getcwd())` to see that it was looking in the wrong directory.

So now you can specify the correct directory.

`title = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('path/to/your/imgs', 'GOLF GAME LOGO.png'))`

You also mentioned in the comment that the image won't open. What do you mean by that?

EDIT: Your new code should look something like that

```
import pygame
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys

pygame.init()
os.chdir(r"C:\Users[name]\Desktop\Projects\PythonProjects\Python Practice\Projects\Games\Golf Game")
print(os.getcwd())

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 600))
title = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'GOLF GAME LOGO.png'))

win.blit(title, (x,y))
```

Comment: My Code:
import pygame
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys 
pygame.init() 
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\[name]\Desktop\Projects\PythonProjects\Python Practice\Projects\Games\Golf Game") 
print(os.getcwd())
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 600))
title = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'GOLF GAME LOGO.png'))

Comment: output:
"C:\Users\[NAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" -m StartScreen
pygame 1.9.6 Hello from the pygame community https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html C:\Users\[NAME]\Desktop\Projects\PythonProjects\Python Practice\Projects\Games\Golf Game Process finished with exit code 0 

this is my output and the process is ended without doing anything like the pygame window opens and then closes instantly with no errors no image

Comment: In the future, please use the markup to indicate code or just edit your question. `exit code 0` means that everything worked ok. If there was an error, `exit` would have a non-zero argument. Nothing is happening because all you have done is set the display mode and loaded an image. You need to draw the image on the screen. `win.blit(title, (x,y))` If my answer has helped you please accept it as the best answer. Thanks and good luck

Comment: still nothing happens i also tried writing pygame.display.update() still nothing comes up

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? Did you draw the image?

Comment: yes i also tried your code in idle just to check but the same thing happens

Comment: output is above